# Any Job server alternatives to Gearman and Zend Server for triggering PHP?

Tags: php, message-queue, gearman, zend-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to format messages for queueing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444157/what-is-the-best-way-to-format-messages-for-queueing)

I'm looking to add a job server to queue non-critical, non-realtime tasks (like sending a welcome email to a user signing up for an account or triggering periodic reports).  We're a small shop with strong PHP experience and would like to be able to create our job scripts in PHP.  We want to be able to easily connect and trigger jobs, be able to monitor the success/failure/perfomance of jobs and be able to requeue and/or re-run failed jobs as needed--hence the need for some basic reporting about jobs.

Ideally, we want to be in the business of creating jobs, not building a home-rolled job server or patching together a number of quasi-vetted packages.  Building and maintaining something from scratch with gearman requires more investment than we want to make.  We tried Zend Server and it looks like it can meet our needs, but I wasn't overly impressed with the reports.

I'd love for there to be something as polished and flexible as say the continues integration / build server Jenkins/Hudson, but geared more towards generic job queuing.

Does anyone have any suggestions or has had success with any other products?

Comment: @Gordon I'm not looking for 'how to send messages', I'm looking for an existing job queue server with built in dashboard reporting.

Comment: @tdlm Nothings wrong with gearman, but it's not a complete job server with reporting and monitoring--it's an API with queuing functionality to build job servers.

Comment: @Ray well, the linked dupe lists a couple of alternatives, so have a look at them to find whether they meet your requirements.